# Merge JSON array values across multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

| UserID | Access |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["1"] |
| 2 | ["2", "3"] |
| 3 | ["3"] |

I have the above table, I'm looking to return a merged array of all the Access values. So the result would be

`["1","2","3"]`

I have tried with:
`SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(Access) FROM table;`

But this results in a concatenated JSON array of arrays like:
`[["1"],["2","3"],["3"]]`

What is the best way of achieving the desired output?

Comment: The easiest way?  Use a scripting language that is meant to handle JSON.  Even `bash` has `jq` - Python, PHP, Node, pick your poison .. They all will be far easier and less convoluted than a pure SQL approach IMHO.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? If you use MySQL >= 8.0.4 you can use [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table), see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QTzHKrQA).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer this showing a PHP variant per my comment .. This is just meant to be helpful and possibly useful as an alternative to a complicated SQL call.

Say you had this table:

| UserID | Access |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["1"] |
| 2 | ["2", "3"] |
| 3 | ["3"] |
| 4 | ["2", "4","7"] |
| 5 | ["1", "5","7"] |
| 6 | ["2", "6"] |

You can use this little bit of PHP to give you exactly what you're looking for using 7 lines of code (provided you make your SQL call).

```
$rows = $getDB->makeQuery("SELECT Access FROM your_table");

$merged_array = array();

foreach ($rows as $row){
    $json = json_decode( $row['Access'] );
    $merged_array = array_unique(array_merge($json, $merged_array));
}
sort($merged_array);
print_r( $merged_array );
$new_json = json_encode($merged_array);
echo $new_json;
```

That will give you a JSON string that looks like:

```
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
```

Every language is different, but rest assured they all have the basic logic I have laid out here ..

1. Create a empty array
2. Loop through each SQL row
3. Convert JSON to array
4. Merge temp array with current row item
5. Rid yourself of duplicates
6. (Loop complete) sort the array (smallest to largest)
7. Convert array back to JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON_TABLE() function (starting with [MariaDB 10.6](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/) or [MySQL 8](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/json_table-the-best-of-both-worlds/)), which can turn your JSON into a relational table, producing rows from array values. Then, you can DISTINCT those values to only keep unique ones.

Let's reuse your existing query that returns you the following result: `[["1"],["2","3"],["3"]]`, to produce a one-line table `j_tbl`, and then join it with JSON_TABLE(), which will return array elements as rows. No need for join condition, since `j_tbl` has only one row.

```sql
WITH j_tbl AS (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(Access) j_col FROM users)
SELECT DISTINCT access_array
FROM j_tbl
JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    j_col,
    '$[*]' COLUMNS(
      NESTED PATH '$[*]' COLUMNS (access_array INT PATH '$')
    )
  ) AS all_accesses;
```

(I presume your table is called `users`. If not, change the name as relevant.)

Answer (score -1):

**TABLE**

```
| id | json_array_column   |
| 1  | ["apple", "banana"] |
| 2  | ["orange", "grape"] |
| 3  | ["pear", "kiwi"]    |
```

**Query**

```
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(item) AS merged_array
FROM (
  SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(json_array_column, CONCAT('$[', numbers.n, ']'))) AS item
  FROM my_table
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 -- Add more numbers here depending on the maximum length of your arrays
  ) AS numbers
) AS items;
```

**output**

```
| merged_array |
| ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape", "pear", "kiwi"] |
```

Comment: What happens when there is only 1 value, then 3 values, then 2 values?  You have to know the highest value here and `SELECT X`.  Which could be 100 values for one field and 3 values for another.   That's problem number 1.  -- So OP has to hard code his query -- bad bad ...  Now after hard coding how many fields is the max number, we have the problem of returning `"null"` for the columns that have less values.   This is a clumsy answer. Test it with OP's data

Comment: Better yet, test it with my data -- `["1", null, null, "2", "3", null, "3", null, null, "2", "4", "7", "1", "5", "7", "2", "6", null]` is the result.